# how to disable click on the img tag under list in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have used list of 4 images one after the other, on clicking each images a content will be opened in the same html page. Now the problem is I want to give specific condition in jQuery such that if i click on **img1** then only click option should appear on **img2**. If i click on **img2** then only click option should appear on **img3**. My code is

```
<ul id="one">
            <li  class="list1"><img id="img1" src="images/assets/tool_deactive.png" > <img class="act1" style="display:none" src="images/assets/tool_active.png"><span class="para">Tools</span>

            <li class="list2"><img id="img2" src="images/assets/protocol_dec.png"Disabled><img class="act2" style="display:none" src="images/assets/protocol_act.png"><span class="para">Protocols</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list3"><img id="img3" src="images/assets/data_dec.png"><img class="act3" style="display:none" src="images/assets/data_act.png"><span class="para">Data Generation</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list4"><img id="img4" src="images/assets/rules_dec.png"><img class="act4" style="display:none" src="images/assets/rules_act.png"><span class="para">Rules</span>
            </li>

        </ul>
```

And my jquery code is

```
$(".list1").click(function() {
        $(".rule2").hide();
        $(".mid1").show();
}
$(".list2").click(function() {
        $(".rule3").hide();
        $(".mid2").show();
}
$(".list3").click(function() {
        $(".rule4").hide();
        $(".mid3").show();
}
$(".list4").click(function() {
        $(".rule1").hide();
        $(".mid4").show();
}
```

How to give codition based clicking options using jQuery?

Comment: have a look at on and off - lets you bind and unbind events, and even maybe one as it looks like you are only wanting to bind a single click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **With Pointer Events**

```js
$(".list").off("click").on("click",function(){
  $(".rule").eq($(this).index()).hide();
  $(".mid").eq($(this).index()).show();
  console.log("Hello")
  $(this).addClass("none-events").next().removeClass("none-events")
})
```

```css
.none-events{
  pointer-events:none;
}
.list{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="one">
            <li  class="list"><img id="img1" src="images/assets/tool_deactive.png" > <img class="act1" style="display:none" src="images/assets/tool_active.png"><span class="para">Tools</span>

            <li class="list none-events"><img id="img2" src="images/assets/protocol_dec.png"Disabled><img class="act2" style="display:none" src="images/assets/protocol_act.png"><span class="para">Protocols</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list none-events"><img id="img3" src="images/assets/data_dec.png"><img class="act3" style="display:none" src="images/assets/data_act.png"><span class="para">Data Generation</span>
            </li>
            <li class="list none-events"><img id="img4" src="images/assets/rules_dec.png"><img class="act4" style="display:none" src="images/assets/rules_act.png"><span class="para">Rules</span>
            </li>

        </ul>
```